# Do ring 0 programs use physical memory addresses?

Tags: operating-system, x86, x86-64, virtual-memory, cpu-architecture

I'm designing a memory chip, and since this seems like the best place to ask a related system software question...

On a modern x86 processor, does system-level code (protection ring 0) run on physical memory addresses?
And is it the same for the 64 bit spec?

(I need to know so I know whether addresses for system code go through the virtual/segmented memory subsystem or not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They run as any other code. The only difference between Ring 0 the other rings is that Ring 0 can execute privileged instructions, and thus modify the memory address space and structure. This privilege, however, does not mean that Ring 0 cannot use virtual memory just like any other code. It is technically possible to run all processes in Ring 0 and maintain the same virtual memory behavior, assuming the processes don't attempt to modify it. It is also possible to run less privileged ring processes without virtual memory address spaces.

Comment: Ah, well. There goes one optimization...  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is still a flat virtual memory model.  Driver code and data can be paged out as normal unless specific countermeasures are made to lock the pages.  A common blue screen stop code is KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR for example.

A typical call to map physical memory is MmAllocatePagesForMdl()